# error list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, integer

Based on the title, help me solve the error.
i've tried to print the countryCode based on country_name which is in 'rv' variable.
country_found is list of data that have the same value on countries list,
and then i try to retrieve countryCode and there i got the error

```
rv = "Indonesia"
country_lower = rv.lower()
countries = {
  "DATA": {
    "data": [{
        "countryId": "26",
        "countryCode": "AU",
        "name": "Australia"
    }, {
        "countryId": "17",
        "countryCode": "ID",
        "name": "Indonesia"
    }]
   }
} 
def take_first(predicate, iterable):
 for element in iterable:
    if predicate(element):
        yield element
        break

country_found = list(
 take_first(
    lambda e: e['name'].lower() == country_lower, 
    countries['DATA']['data']
 )
)

default_country_code = 'US'
country_code = (
  country_found['countryCode'] 
  if country_found 
  else default_country_code
)
print (country_code)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*`country_found` is a list*, but you are trying to get an item by a string index:

```
country_found['countryCode']
```

You've probably meant to get the first result of a match:

```
country_code = country_found[0]['countryCode'] if country_found else default_country_code
```

But, do you actually need to have the result as a list, what if you would just use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
result = take_first(lambda e: e['name'].lower() == country_lower, 
                    countries['DATA']['data'])
try:
    country_code = next(result)['countryCode']
except StopIteration:
    country_code = default_country_code
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, below is what you might want to look into.

```
default_country_code = 'US'
print(country_found) # ==> list [{'countryId': '17', 'name': 'Indonesia', 'countryCode': 'IN'}]
print(country_found[0]) # ==> dictionary {'countryId': '17', 'name': 'Indonesia', 'countryCode': 'IN'}
print(country_found[0].get('countryCode',default_country_code)) # get countryCode. If countryCode is not there, get the default_country_code
```