# How to sort list of dictionaries by average of specified value

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting, dictionary

Write a function named `sort_by_average_rating` that takes a list/array of key-value stores as a parameter where each key-value store has keys "**ratings**", "**budget**", and "**box_office**" where "budget" and "box_office" are integers and "ratings" is a list of integers.

Sort the input based on the average of the values in "ratings".

```
def sort_by_average_rating(lista):
    lista.sort(sum(lista['ratings']) / int(len(lista['ratings'])))
    return lista
```

I am getting error on input:

> error on input [{'ratings': [9, 10, 2, 3, 8, 10, 9], 'budget': 16219606.11, 'box_office': 13297812}, {'ratings': [6, 3, 1, 7, 9, 2], 'budget': 12995254.35, 'box_office': 26409035}] list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Expected Output:

```
[{'ratings': [6, 3, 1, 7, 9, 2], 'budget': 12995254.35, 'box_office': 26409035}, {'ratings': [9, 10, 2, 3, 8, 10, 9], 'budget': 16219606.11, 'box_office': 13297812}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: key, values are for dictionaries, not lists. [mcve] please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error list indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088460/error-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str)

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says you have this list of dictionaries:

```
L = [{'ratings': [9, 10, 2, 3, 8, 10, 9], 'budget': 16219606.11, 'box_office': 13297812},
     {'ratings': [6, 3, 1, 7, 9, 2], 'budget': 12995254.35, 'box_office': 26409035}]
```

You can just use `sorted` with a custom `key` function:

```
res = sorted(L, key=lambda x: sum(x['ratings']) / len(x['ratings']))

[{'box_office': 26409035, 'budget': 12995254.35, 'ratings': [6, 3, 1, 7, 9, 2]},
 {'box_office': 13297812, 'budget': 16219606.11, 'ratings': [9, 10, 2, 3, 8, 10, 9]}]
```

Alternatively, you can use `statistics.mean`:

```
from statistics import mean

res = sorted(L, key=lambda x: mean(x['ratings']))
```

Notice the `lambda` function takes each item in your iterable (`L`) rather than the entire list of dictionaries (as in your current attempt).